# Can a burned music that is separated from another folder be played?

Tags: music, dvd, cd

I don't know where I should post it but it's some kind of related to music.
So, I burned music with my CD, first I make folder where all music that will be burned placed, then I burn it through Windows Media Player, after that I realized that 2 of my music files is placed inside a separate folder.


**Question**: Will it all still play when I plug it inside my CD/DVD Player ? Plays accordingly to its given numbered file name ?

Comment: I'm not sure why a separate folder was made... can you give me a screenshot of the contents of the CD and the contents of the folder?

Comment: Windows comes with a screenshot tool called "Snipping Tool" it completely free. It's in start->all programs->accessories->snipping tool

Comment: @Daniel I just solved the problem, the reason why it creates a new folder because because of the specified Album name of specific music, then this is how  I solve it, I remove the Album name in it's properties -> details or I just empty the music details and its done

Comment: Hi Kentz. You can answer your own question if you wish.